# How can I securely connect to databases in GKE using GUI tools?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, table-plus

I'd like to connect to my databases in GKE using GUI tools but I don't want to expose the services to the world. What are some ways to accomplish this?

Update: for instance, I'd like to use TablePlus to connect to a mysql pod inside the cluster.

Comment: Can you please give more detail to your question? Where are you DB? Which type of DB are? Are those in the same project? Is your DB into a VM or is it a Cloud SQL, Big table, Big Query solution?

Comment: Hey Marlen, sorry to keep rejecting your edit. Maybe I'm missing something, my pod is running in Google Kubernetes Engine so I feel like the tag is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new VM in the region where your cluster lives.
2. Install the GUI tool.
3. Specify an IP address in the cluster's IP range.

See the example below, which describes how to connect to a database which is running on a GKE cluster.
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-database